# Bash script that finds longest shortest filename in loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

Hi so i got a homework i am trying to get longest and shortest length filename in this loop i tried piping awk but it didnt work it always writes all of the files with filename's string count number
i need to loop through that array and record the shortest and longest index need to check longest and shortest script filename in that paths, dirs array have and i have to sort it by just filename but output need to be like this longest filename =15 character /usr/sbin/update-info-dir

it works like this now
longest filename =3 character /usr/sbin/ufw

longest filename =22 character /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates

longest filename =15 character /usr/sbin/update-info-dir

longest filename =16 character /usr/sbin/update-initramfs

longest filename =13 character /usr/sbin/update-locale

longest filename =11 character /usr/sbin/update-mime
.... and scans all files stored at array like this
i want to  show just longest and shortest file with path same way as  above

Comment: You're not looking at the length of the filename anywhere. Your script appears to iterate across all directories in `$PATH` and attempt to print the name of every script in each directory

Comment: oh sory let me edit

Comment: Are you just looking for the length of a filename or the path? And is it in general, or why are you iterating through the directories in `$PATH`?

Comment: I am looking for longest and shortest length name  of script's filename and my tutor wants it with array like that

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please clarify as much as you can. Apparently, you mean directory and filename. Should it be based on the current directory, or the root directory, or a specific one, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing your requirement for the script is relatively unclear.

I understand you must use an array, and you have to sort by file name and path length.

This scriptlet does exactly that, but given your example I'm not 100% sure whether you need to loop over the array specifically, or construct the array in some other way. Also, I don't understand your use of `$PATH`, hence I've omitted that for now:

```
files=( $(find . -type f | awk '{ print length, $0 }' | sort -n -s | cut -d' ' -f2-) )

echo "shortest: ${files[0]}"
echo "longest: ${files[-1]}"
```

Note the scriptlet requires at least Bash version 4.2 (for the negative indexing in arrays). It searches the current directory, you can specify the directory as the first parameter of `find`.

If you must use a loop, you can simply not sort the array, instead you loop through that array and record the shortest and longest index. It is somewhat unclear, if that is a requirement. Doing this with looping over the array wouldn't make much sense, so unless it is a requirement, I'd advice against it.

Comment: thanks for the answer i need to loop through that array and record the shortest and longest index otherwise  with this code u shared i am just getting result for current directory im in but i need to check longest and shortest script filename  in that paths dirs array have and i have to sort it by just filename but output need to be like this longest filename =15 character /usr/sbin/update-info-dir

Comment: @Luissantangel I explained in the latter part of the answer, how the directory is selectable as the first parameter of `find`. You didn't specify all the filenames are in the array you're given. Please be more specific in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Show shortest:

```
awk '{split($0,items,":");for (item in items){print length(items[item])" "items[item]}}'<<<"$PATH"|sort -nk1|head -n1
```

show longest:

```
awk '{split($0,items,":");for (item in items){print length(items[item])" "items[item]}}'<<<"$PATH"|sort -nk1|tail -n1
```